# Typescript absolute module paths not compiling correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am relatively new to typescript so maybe I am missing something here or don't fully understand the concept. In tsconfig I have defined the following in compilerOptions:

```js
{
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    "*": ["server/*"]
  }
}
```

Assuming the following directory structure:

```js
+ server
|  + routes
|  |  + util
|  |  - config.routes.ts
|  - route_file.ts
-tsconfig.json
```

If I import a module exported by route_file.ts in config.routes.ts:

```js
import * as routes from 'routes/route_file.ts';
```

Typescript resolves the path without issue. The compiled JS, however, requires the module with the same literal path:

```js
const routes = require('routes/route_file')
```

This is obviously a problem because the module will not be found as the path should be ../route_file. My project has quite a few sub directories and I was hoping to get away from ../../../ if possible. Is there a way to make the compiler check the directory of the importing file and update the require path relative to that file?

Comment: Have you tried to import from an absolute path like '/server/route_file'?

Comment: Hi @Zofskeez, I had the same question and found an answer, maybe this can be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657948/create-module-containing-all-exports-in-typescript/43886685#43886685

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the tsconfig only tells the typescript compiler where to find the type information. The resolving of the paths is a task for the bundler like webpack. Or the runtime executing the JavaScript.
If you want to have a look on a working configuration with webpack you can check out a sample with react I set up a few weeks ago https://github.com/kaoDev/react-ts-sample